# Initializing variables of a class in header

Tags: c++, sfml

I am new to C++, coming over from Java.
As my first project I want to make a simple little SFML game.
I have separated the main file into header and cpp file.
Basically I am initializing the SFML RenderWindow in the cpp class.
As you can see here:

```
Main::Main() {
    this->wWidth = 1440;
    this->wHeight = 900;
    this->wTitle = "Platformer";
    this->fps = 0;
    this->window = sf::RenderWindow(VideoMode(this->wWidth, this->wHeight), this->wTitle);
    this->player = Player(100, 100, this->window);
}
```

My Header file:

```
class Main {
    public:
        Main();

        void tick();
        void render();
        void run();
        void spawn();
        int main();

        float fps;
    private:
        int wWidth = 1440;
        int wHeight = 900;
        std::string wTitle = "Platformer";
        sf::RenderWindow window;
        Player player;
};
```

Now this may be an issue of me coming from Java but I want to create an empty instance of the `sf::RenderWindow` in the header, and then initialize it the main file.

But it won't work the `sf::RenderWindow` being passed to the `Player` initialization *won't work*. If someone can tell me the proper way to do this in C++ rather than the way that you would do it in Java, that would be good as I don't fully understand the C++ terminology yet.

The Errors I am getting:

For this:

`Main::Main() {`

---

`no matching function for call to 'Player::Player()'`

For this:

`this->window = sf::RenderWindow(VideoMode(this->wWidth, this->wHeight), this->wTitle);`

---

`use of deleted function 'sf::RenderWindow& sf::RenderWindow::operator=(const sf::RenderWindow&)'`

For this:

`this->player = Player(100, 100, this->window);`

---

`use of deleted function 'Player& Player::operator=(Player&&)'`

For this

`class Player {`

---

`non-static reference member 'sf::RenderWindow& Player::window', can't use default assignment operator`

Comment: When you say it "won't work" what exactly is the error you're getting?

Comment: Why won't it work? There's nothing in your description of the actual problem, only 'it doesn't work'

Comment: @john I have now given the errrors I am getting

Comment: @JMAA I have now given the errrors I am getting

Comment: In c++, by the time you reach the first line of the constructor, an object of that type (`this`) already exists, with all members default-initialised unless the initialisation is specified in a member initialisation list https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Comment: please stop writing this-> before member variables, it is implicit so not needed

Comment: @AndersK It's not needed, but it's a matter of taste and style. I've seen style guides that encourage it (and I fully understand why)

Comment: Can you extract a [mcve] and post that as part of your question? Also, reconsider whether that minimal example is actually relevant to SFML.

Answer (score 2):

If `sf::RenderWindow` does not have a default constructor you must initalise it in `Main`'s initalisation list. This is because you have declared `window` to be an automatic object member of `Main`, and so it must be constructed along with all the other members of `Main` when `Main` is constructed. You should also use an initalisation list anyway as it is much more efficent.

Like this:

```cpp
Main::Main() : fps(0), window(VideoMode(wWidth, wHeight), wTitle)), player(100, 100, window)  {}
```

(You do not need to initalise all the other members as they have been default initalised by the `=` in the header)

Answer (score 2):

You have to remember that in C++ objects are not pointers. All objects are constructed at the point the object is created. So in the case of your player object

```
Main::Main() {
    ...
    this->player = Player(100, 100, this->window);
}
```

creates the Player object then assigns to it. It attempts to create the player object with it's default constructor but since that doesn't exist you get an error message. This is the way you should do it

```
Main::Main() : player(100, 100, window) {
    ...
}
```

Similarly with `window`

```
Main::Main() : window(VideoMode(wWidth, wHeight), wTitle),
    player(100, 100, window) {
    ...
}
```

Now it's possible that some of these objects really should be pointers, I wouldn't know about that. But hopefully, you now understand the difference in c++ between initialisation and assignment.

Comment: Thanks I kind of understood the difference before but didn't really know how to apply these differences, I think that will come with time though. You have properly explained the difference between initialization and assignment